# TF_AllocateTensor: is the last "len" argument redundant?

Tags: c, tensorflow

The C API of tensorflow provides a `TF_AllocateTensor` function:

```
// Allocate and return a new Tensor.
//
// This function is an alternative to TF_NewTensor and should be used when
// memory is allocated to pass the Tensor to the C API. The allocated memory
// satisfies TensorFlow's memory alignment preferences and should be preferred
// over calling malloc and free.
//
// The caller must set the Tensor values by writing them to the pointer returned
// by TF_TensorData with length TF_TensorByteSize.
TF_CAPI_EXPORT extern TF_Tensor* TF_AllocateTensor(TF_DataType,
                                                   const int64_t* dims,
                                                   int num_dims, size_t len);
```

Now the doc for the C API seems to consist in header comments only, but from what I saw searching from code fragments using this function, the value that is provided for `len` is always equal to `sizeof_data_type * prod(dims)`.

What is the use of this parameter if it can be deduced from the others? Is there a use case where `len` can be something else than `sizeof_data_type * prod(dims)`?

Comment: You can look at [the source code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.0.0/tensorflow/c/tf_tensor.cc#L101-L148) to see how `len` is used in `TF_AllocateTensor` and `TF_NewTensor`, looks like it's used for alloc/dealloc and memcpy, and it's not until the very end that its value is checked. It's true that in virtually all cases the value of `len` will be calculated as you say... It may be that they wanted an API more explicit about the allocated memory size. Also, this allows you to allocate a buffer larger than necessary, although it's hard to think when that might be useful...